# Validating Jpa Entities: In service or by lifecycle listeners

Tags: java, validation, architecture, jpa, design-patterns

The question is where it is better (or in other words: where do you prefer) to put business validation logic of Jpa Entities.

Two ideas are:

1. In the EntityListener that before save or update would validate the entity
2. In the service that provides access to jpa persisting methods.

There are pros and cons of both. 
When using approach No. 2 it is easier to test as you may just mock the jpa provider and test the validation logic. On the other hand with approach No. 1 the validation would happen at the same moment with validations like @NotNull etc.

I would love to know how do you solve validations in your projects and which is the better way to go.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a general thumb rule that I follow:

> When using bean validation, specify
>   rules that do not require dependencies
>   on other beans. The moment you depend
>   on another bean, get your service
>   layer to handle that dependency.

In other words, if you have a reference to a bean inside another, avoid putting in that @NotNull constraint. Your service layer is best used for that, for you're catching the violation much earlier, and at a more logical point (since other business validations would assume that the beans are available).

As an example, consider the following entity (apologies for it wont compile)

```
@Entity
public class User
{
   @Id
   private int id;
   @NotNull
   private String fullName;
   @NotNull
   private String email;
   private Set<Role> roles; //No bean validation constraints here.
   ...
   public boolean mapRoleToUser(Role role)
   { //Validation is done here. Including checks for a null role.
   }

}

@Entity
public class Role
{
  @Id
  private int id;
  @NotNull
  private String name;
}
```

The service layer in this case, is the one that should validate whether the user has a role attached or not. Verification in the pre-persist or pre-update phase is a bit too late, especially when there is a distinct service layer that has business logic, and the rest of the business logic in the domain model (sadly, I haven't seen a good enough application with all of the logic in the domain model alone).